# How to find the value of $\Gamma (0^+)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gamma-function

This question was part of my complex analysis assignment and I am not able to solve it.

> Find the value of $\Gamma (0^+)$ . (It could be $-\infty $ or $+\infty$.)

I used the formula of gamma function which is $\Gamma (z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t} dt $ and I got by putting $z =0^+ $, $\Gamma (0^+)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1/x ) e^{-x} dx$ and if I integrate it by parts I get
it equal $-\infty-\int_{0}^{\infty}(1/x^2) e^{-x}dx$ .

If I again use integrating by parts  to $\int_{0}^{\infty}(1/x^2) e^{-x}dx$ and do it sucessively the power of $x$ will become more negative. So, I am not able to solve the integral.

Can you please tell how to do it?

Comment: Notice that the integral is surely positive and divergent at $x=0$, so it must be equal to $+\infty$

Comment: By the functional equation, $\Gamma (x) = \frac{1}{x}x\Gamma (x) = \frac{1}{x}\Gamma (x + 1)$. Now just note that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0 + } \Gamma (x + 1) = \Gamma (1) = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Gamma(0)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\mathrm{d}x$$
Let $u=\log(x)$. Then
$$\Gamma(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-e^u)\mathrm{d}u$$
Which certainly diverges to $+\infty$ since the integrand is $\approx 1$ for $u\to-\infty$ and $\approx 0$ for $u\to\infty$.

Comment: @metamorphy I meant to write 0. Oops. Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 0):

Also from this point of view to see the singularities.
$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+n+1)}{z(z+1)\cdots(z+n)}$$
The denominator will be zero with $z=0, -1, -2, \ldots$ for all non-positive integers.

So gamma function will be undefined at those points to avoid division by zero.